# JScrollPane - automatically scroll to bottom?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I've been trying to create a a scroll pane that automatically keeps scrolling down as the user adds more lines of text to the window. I implemented this:

```
pane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        e.getAdjustable().setValue(e.getAdjustable().getMaximum());  
    }
});
```

"pane" is a JScrollPane that is holding a JList.

Unfortunately, the code above sticks the scroll bar to the bottom of the pane (which is what I wanted) but then I am unable to move the scroll bar from its position (so now it's stuck at the bottom). Is there a simple way to have the scroll bar stick to the bottom, but still be able to be scrolled elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add an item to the JList you can use the method:

```
list.ensureIndexIsVisible(...)
```

where the index is the index of the last item in the list.

Comment: Ok, but what if you add the element from an 'AbstractListModel'.  In it, I fire the fireIntervalAdded of the ListModel, but how do I then ask the JList to scroll.

I have taught about capturing the addition of an element in a JList event, but I cannot find any such event.
I have taught about scrolling directly from the ListModel, but since this ListModel could be used in multiple JLists, how do I get a reference to the bound JList(s) from within the ListModel???